# Angular image zoom hover effect

Tags: angular

i am a fresher in angular.
can you tell me which zoom hover effect will work in ecommerce product image?

Also I have tried ngx-img-zoom npm but not working.

```
//test.component.html
  <ngx-img-zoom
  [zoomImageSrc]="zoomImageSrc"
  [previewImageSrc]="previewImageSrc" 
  [imgStyle]="'width:515px; height:515px; bottom:0;  left:0;  right:0;  top:0;  margin:0 auto; border:1px solid #dcdcdc;'" 
  [resultStyle]="`width:824px; height:824px; background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index: 2; position:absolute;
                 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
                  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24); top: 0;left: 100%;`"
  [lensStyle]="'width:155px; height:155px"
  [enableZoom] = "enableZoom"
  [containerStyle]=""
></ngx-img-zoom>
```

```
//test.component.ts
  constructor(private ngxImgZoom: NgxImgZoomService) {
    this.ngxImgZoom.setZoomBreakPoints([{w: 100, h: 100}, {w: 150, h: 150}, {w: 200, h: 200}, {w: 250, h: 250}, {w: 300, h: 300}]);
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to do and what you've tried? I would imagine standard html + css would get most jobs done, and if not, maybe you're making it harder than it needs to be?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57396846/angular-7-image-zoom/57402944#57402944

Answer (score 4):

You can active using

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-zoom

```
    npm i ngx-image-zoom
```

> Here is [working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-image-zoom-5trkhe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

```js
Import it to your `App Module`

    import { NgxImageZoomModule } from 'ngx-image-zoom';
    
    @NgModule({
      imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, NgxImageZoomModule ],
      declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
      bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

then

```html
    <lib-ngx-image-zoom
        [thumbImage]=myThumbnail
        [fullImage]=myFullresImage
        [magnification]="1"
        [enableScrollZoom]="true"
        [enableLens]="true"
        [lensWidth]="200"
    ></lib-ngx-image-zoom>
```

declare image in your **.ts** file

```
myThumbnail="https://wittlock.github.io/ngx-image-zoom/assets/thumb.jpg";
  myFullresImage="https://wittlock.github.io/ngx-image-zoom/assets/fullres.jpg";
```

Comment: I tried doing that npm , it is showing zoom effect in that same image but i want to keep that zoom effect beside the image.

Comment: wait how do you want to active it ? i will check code.

Comment: Tried that in Angular 9 and the latest version of this library, it doesn't work. The images are having 0 width and height. It seems that it is a common bug which the developer of this library didn't fix yet :/

Comment: For me I was using minio urls in Angular 10 application . The library did not work in my case. 

Minio Url - A url coming from a cloud storage called Minio where you are asked to download the image once accessing the url. (May have to cache the image first to show in the web)

Answer (score 0):

There is no properly working npm package for Angular image zoom except [ng-img-magnifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-img-magnifier).
Here is the working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-img-magnifier).

Install:

```
npm i ng-img-magnifier
```

Implementation:

```
<ng-img-magnifier
[thumbImage]='img' [fullImage]='img2'>
</ng-img-magnifier>
```

For lens, thumbnail, and zoom customisation try:

```
<ng-img-magnifier [thumbImage]='img' [fullImage]='img2'
[top]='top' [right]='right'
[lensWidth]='lensewidth' [lensHeight]='lensheight'
[resultWidth]='resultWidth' [resultHeight]='resultheight'
[imgWidth]='imgWidth' [imgHeight]='imgheight'> 
</ng-img-magnifier>
```

This image zoom similar to Amazon or W3school will work for you.

I hope this will resolve your issue.